# Consuming WebApi Service "like an asmx service"

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Ok, so I want to have a self-hosted WebApi service, the reason for this is to then have a mixture of RESTful based methods as well as providing "old school" access to my service.

To try to explain better if I had the following method

```
public string SendDocument(Document document)
```

Document being a "DataContract" how would I go about consuming this like you would for a WCF/ASMX Web Service.

As far as I can tell I cannot create a proxy class or add the WebApi as a service reference, so how would I go about consuming this method?

I know this is a bit of an open question, but I have been searching for the last 2 hours and not getting very far...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for a proxy. You could use the `HttpClient` class: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-clients/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client

Comment: Ok, but I was hoping that the users would still be able to access some wsdl and generate a proxy class based upon the WebMethods I have exposed. So then the user would could consume the service in the same fashion.    
`Document d = new Document();  
ProxyClass pc = new ProxyClass();    
pc.SendDocument(d);`

Comment: Nope. This is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use WCF to serve both SOAP and REST requests.

Comment: Yes I know thanks, but the decision has been to be WebApi (don't get me started :))

Comment: Can you create a separate endpoint just for SOAP requests? Assuming your SendDocument method implementation is not directly in the Web API action method, but a separate class, it would only be a few lines of code to expose a SOAP endpoint using WCF.